# xcode ios build linker command failed with exit code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipa

I am trying to archive (create an IPA) for a project, but I get stuck with the following error...

```
ld: '/Users/anupsaund/Desktop/mobileapp-ios/GoogleAnalytics/libAdIdAccess.a(TAGActualAdIdAccess.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Users/anupsaund/Desktop/mobileapp-ios/GoogleAnalytics/libAdIdAccess.a' for architecture armv7
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image]

Can anyone help me understand where the error could be?
IS it in the google analytics library or somewhere else?

How would I go about getting the verbosity via Xcode to show me the calling code where the error threw?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bitcode is enabled in your project settings but your app was compiled without it. To fix this you can simply set Enable Bitcode in the project and library settings to No. Hope this helped!

Comment: How do you do this?

Comment: Choose your Target -> Build Settings -> Enable Bitcode -> No